# Refreshing PopUp content in GeoJSON layer in leaflet

Tags: popup, leaflet, geojson

I am loading a geojson file using leaflet's L.geoJSON() to display a map.

Initially i have attahced a popup with each feature.The popup shows a certain property "Count". The code is:

```
var geoJSON = new L.geoJson(var_name,{
        onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){layer.bindPopup('Count :'+feature.properties.Count);},
        style: applyStyle
    }).addTo(map);
```

This code works fine.

After this, the user initiates an event and i make an ajax call and assign new values to the property "Count" of each feature. I also use the setStyle function so that the style is reassigned based on new values of "Count". Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'new_data.json',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){

var i;
for(i=0;i<48;i++){

var_name.features[i].properties.Count = data[i];
}
 geoJSON.setStyle(applyStyle);

}
});
```

The style changes work well but the popup still contains the old value for the property "Count". 
There is so setPopUp function like setStyle. So how do i make the popUp change its value?

In other words, can we call the onEachFeature method again after the geoJSON layer has been loaded?

P.S.:  I am not using same popup content for each feature. After i make the ajax call, i update the "Count" property of each feature. I want the pop-up for each feature to show the value of its new value of "Count" property.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing now is using the `setStyle` method of your `L.GeoJSON` layer, which when called, iterates all the features contained in the layer and calls the `setStyle` method of each feature. (If the feature has a `setStyle` method). Since there is no `setPopup` method in `L.GeoJSON`. (it's a very rare use case if you would want the same popup content on each feature) you'll have to iterate the features in your GeoJSON layer yourself and set the new content on the popup itself:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojsonCollection, {
    'onEachFeature': function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('Initial content');
    }
}).addTo(map);

geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer._popup.setContent('Updated content')
});
```

Here's an example on Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/uYHC8jZtgls351YhsmPS/preview

Comment: I would have thought that just rebinding a popup would have been enough: `layer.bindPopup("Updated content")`, so that answer to Op's last question would have been simply "yes" (demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/AvX8FdZ0RU9aNBlFCM1m?p=preview) except that after init you use [`eachLayer` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) rather than `onEachFeature` option.

Comment: Ofcourse, that's a solution too. Although the proper way would be to unbind the current popup first. Looks cleaner and doesn't use a private ( _ prefixed) property. But i just found an even better way, is undocumented but it seems that the setPopupContent (only documented for L.Marker: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setpopupcontent) method is inherited by every layer extended from L.Layer. I'll update my answer.

Comment: wait a minute… This is true for Leaflet 1.0, not for 0.7?.. but it looks like your demo does not complain and still does the job…

Comment: Damn, you're right. It doesn't complain since it's markers in the demo and they've always supported setPopupContent. I'll revert my edit. :D

Comment: But I am not using same popup content for each feature.  After i make the ajax call, i update the "Count" property of each feature. I want the pop-up for each feature to show the value of its  "Count" property.

Answer (score 0):

Using the each layer function as suggested by @iH8 , i was able to do this in the following way:

```
    var j = 0; geoJSON.eachLayer(function (layer){
    layer._popup.setContent("new count = " + var_name.features[j++].properties.Count);
```